# How can I get a valid rank counter?

Tags: mariadb, order-by, mariadb-10.5

I'm making a raking system. I want get the line in one request.

Here is a DB fiddle of my complete example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3Com2wnrhaqfiTKqJSZtft/0

In the example, the UUID used is `36619b04-4fbe-4ba9-8bd6-aaba7df74bb6`. As the first query show, it should be 4. But the second query return 2. The `+1` in the query is to start ranking at 1 instead of 0. The `date_created` column is for a second ordering (if same value, we check according to date). With this system, it force to have a unique rank (there is no equality).

Actually, with the first request, I get the ranking in my program with a simple increment. But, for the second query I can't as I want the rank of someone that could be the 12502th.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What version of MySQL?  8.0 has `RANK()` and `DENSE_RANK()`.

Comment: @RickJames I just updated. Through I were using mysql but no, it's mariadb

Comment: 10.2 has those "windowing functions".

Comment: @RickJames Before posting my question, I tried the `RANK()` method but everyone were at rank 1 (or I got syntax issue)

Comment: Let's see your code.  Consider `RANK()-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ROW_NUMBER](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_number/) window function.

Consider the following data example.

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  uuid VARCHAR(36),
  stats INT,
  date_created TIMESTAMP,
  
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO test(uuid, stats, date_created) VALUES
('97cc165a-0a2e-495e-a99c-7df93e1f1e27', 10, TIMESTAMP('2023-05-24')),
('064c3448-973b-4794-b953-8a862787b971', 8, TIMESTAMP('2023-05-24')),
('36619b04-4fbe-4ba9-8bd6-aaba7df74bb6', 5, TIMESTAMP('2023-05-24')),
('377b8f52-ce94-4dac-baf8-9e07c6e58ae9', 5, TIMESTAMP('2023-04-23')),
('2c4e0f40-078a-4bd6-a405-82813d4cb569', 5, TIMESTAMP('2023-06-28'));
```

Query:

```
select  id, uuid, stats, date_created, rn
from (select *,
              row_number() over (order by stats desc, date_created desc ) rn
       from test
) x
where uuid ='36619b04-4fbe-4ba9-8bd6-aaba7df74bb6';
```

Result:

| id | uuid | stats | date_created | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 36619b04-4fbe-4ba9-8bd6-aaba7df74bb6 | 5 | 2023-05-24 00:00:00 | 4 |

Comment: Oh, it's necessary to make a sub query? Does it impact performances to run over 10k lines?

Comment: @Elikill58 *it's necessary to make a sub query?* , yes it is. With proper indexes you shouldn't have any problem.