# How to fix performance issue with row_number and multiple schema?

Tags: query-performance, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

After receiving answer to [How can I get a valid rank counter?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/325994/203092), I adapted to my own system. But now, I have a performance issue. All of my requests are very fast (less than 0.0005s for most of them), but when using `ROW_NUMBER()` with multiple schemas, it take more than 0.2s.

Here is a complete example:

**Schema 1**, named `sanctions`, with a table named `bans` and composed of:

- `id`, auto increment field
- `uuid`, varchar with index
- others content not linked with question

This table actual have more than 400 rows.

**Schema 2**, named `stats`, with a table named `players` and composed of:

- `id`, auto increment field
- `uuid`, varchar with index
- `coins`, double
- others content not linked with question

This table actual have more than 2000 rows.

**My complete query is like that**:

```sql
SELECT
   uuid,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM sanctions.bans WHERE uuid = p.uuid) as nb,
   row_number() OVER (order by coins DESC) counter
FROM stats.players p;
```

It takes around 0.22s.

Now, let's **check part by part**:

When running `SELECT count(*) FROM arkbans.litebans_bans WHERE uuid = p.uuid` (and by replacing `p.uuid` by a value), I never go more than 0.0002s.

When running:

```sql
SELECT
   uuid,
   row_number() OVER (order by coins DESC) counter
FROM stats.players p;
```

It takes around 0.0017s.

With `ANALYZE` key:

[image]

With `ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON` : [here](https://pastebin.com/nFNEhrDM)

Query analyzed:

```sql
WITH Bans AS
(
    SELECT uuid, COUNT(*) AS BanCount
    FROM sanctions.bans
    GROUP BY uuid
)
 
SELECT
   p.uuid,
   COUNT(b.BanCount) as nb,
   row_number() OVER (order by MAX(p.coins) DESC) counter
FROM stats.players p
LEFT JOIN Bans b ON p.uuid = b.uuid
```

How can I fix this performance issue?

Note: the column "coins" here is an example. In reality, more than 60 columns will use this request. So add index for each column like this is not an option for me (too many index, with too different values)

Note 2: Can't do a db fiddle as it's on multiple database and with lot of data, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When running `SELECT count(*) FROM arkbans.litebans_bans WHERE uuid = p.uuid` (and by replacing `p.uuid` by a value), I never go more than 0.0002s.

Yea running it for a single `uuid` is only 0.0002s but how many rows / `uuid`s are there in your `stats.players` table? And if you multiply that count by 0.0002s, how long is the total runtime now? That's effectively what you're doing when you have an inlined expression in your `SELECT` list that filters on a given row of the outer table. (It's not exactly the same thing, but close enough for you to get the idea.)

You should write your query in a more relationally performant way, with an actual `JOIN`, like so:

```
WITH Bans AS
(
    SELECT uuid, COUNT(1) AS BanCount
    FROM sanctions.bans
    GROUP BY uuid
)

SELECT
   p.uuid,
   IFNULL(b.BanCount, 0) as nb,
   row_number() OVER (order by p.coins DESC) counter
FROM stats.players p
LEFT JOIN Bans b
    ON p.uuid = b.uuid;
```

You may find this re-write even more performant, by directly joining and then grouping the results:

```
SELECT
   p.uuid,
   COUNT(b.BanCount) as nb,
   row_number() OVER (order by MAX(p.coins) DESC) counter
FROM stats.players p
LEFT JOIN sanctions.bans b
    ON p.uuid = b.uuid
GROUP BY p.uuid;
```

As mentioned in the comments, an index on `(uuid, coins)` on the `stats.players` table may be better suited for your type of query.

---

Your `ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON` is showing that most of the time is spent on `sanctions.bans`. Specifically this line is interesting:

> "attached_condition": "trigcond(stats.p.uuid = convert(b.uuid using utf8mb4))"

This `convert(b.uuid using utf8mb4)` indicates to me that your `uuid` column in the `sanctions.bans` table is a different character set than the one in the `stats.players` table. This is called implicit conversion, and can cause performance issues. Intuitively I feel like this is your bottleneck. Please verify and make sure that both fields are the same character sets (and collations).

Comment: @Elikill58 Sorry, I see MariaDB changed that in recent versions. Could you please try using [`ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-format-json/) instead?

Comment: Sure. [here](https://pastebin.com/nFNEhrDM) is the json (I also added it into the question)

Comment: Thanks ! It well because of the uuid column charset. The table `stats.players` is using `utf8mb4_general_ci` and `sanctions.ban` were using `utf8_unicode_ci`. I changed the ban table and now there is normal time (around 0.0012s). And if I put again the wrong charset, I'm back at 0.12s

Comment: @Elikill58 Awesome! Glad we were able to find the root issue in the query plan (`ANALYZE`). That's usually one of the best places to look for performance issues / tuning. 